# Mysql UNIQUE notation with (n)

Tags: mysql, sql

I dont get the `(200)` part of this notation for a MySQL table

```
CREATE TABLE `file_names` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`file_name` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `file_name` (`file_name`(200))
)
```

What effect does the `(200)` part have?

Do you know about other DBs that uses this notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the length option to an index.  It uses only the first 200 characters of `file_name` to validate uniqueness.

It is documented in the `CREATE INDEX` part of the documentation, which is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).

The choice of types is curious.  `text` seems too long for a filename.  And, usually file names differ at the ends of their names, not the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. I found the code here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html :)